# Is there a javascript way to check if a browser natively supports MP3?

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

If the browser can play MP3's then I'll use the audio tag to play a file. If not, I'll have to load in a flash player.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var audio  = document.createElement("audio"),
canPlayMP3 = (typeof audio.canPlayType === "function" &&
              audio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg;codecs=mp3") !== "");
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to use JavaScript (yes, this will work in browsers that support `<audio>` but not MP3), try this:

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="some-audio-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg;codecs=mp3" />
<!-- if you have an Opus version, also include this:
<source src="some-audio-file.opus" type="audio/ogg;codecs=opus" />
-->
<!-- flash object goes here -->
</audio>
```

If you want auto-play, include an `autoplay` attribute on the audio element.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the code that displays the flash sound player in the  tag.

Edit : Use the canPlayType function : http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/media-elements.html#dom-navigator-canplaytype
You can also look at the error attribute : http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/media-elements.html#dom-media-error

Comment: you mean like this <audio src='some.mp3'><!-- FLASH HERE --></audio>? That wouldn't work because Chrome (for example) supports the audio tag, but not MP3.

Comment: thanks. that led me to this detailed explanation... http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/