# Detecting Mobile Devices That Can't Stream MP3 - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-agent, mobile-devices

I am developing an MVC mobile web where I return an audio file depending on the URL parameters.

I want to add a condition where I **return mp3 files** for smartphones,
and **return dm files** for old mobile devices that cannot stream mp3 files

Is there a standard procedure that detects old devices or should I loop through all my options?

Comment: can maybe look at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and construct a list of all the old cellphones that can't stream mp3?

Comment: @JeandrePentz This seems like my last resort. Keeping in consideration that I can never have a definite full list of all the devices that can't read mp3 unless I test them all

Comment: Yes I understand what you want, but I don't believe there is way of detecting if mobile supports mp3.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8469184/1581026 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1514759/1581026

Comment: @JeandrePentz Very useful thanks. This function is on HTML5 though and I'm working on the controller side

Comment: you can maybe on your page loads execute that javascript and then save the value in a cookie so you can easily get the value server side.

Answer (score 0):

Check below two links if they are useful

```
http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2013/04/device-detection-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html
http://techbrij.com/display-mode-mobile-tablet-tv-aspnet-mvc
```

Update:
get device

```
$.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: I already went through these links and a lot of similar others, but they all talk about how to differ between mobile devices and PC/Mac. What I need is to detect devices that can't read mp3

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an **undefined list** of devices that don't play mp3,
The safest way to do this is to state the devices **that do play mp3**,
and I'll leave the rest to the Else Clause.

```
 If userAgent.Contains("iphone;") Or 
    userAgent.Contains("ipad;") Or 
    userAgent.Contains("symbianos;") Or
    userAgent.Contains("ipod;") Or 
    userAgent.Contains("android;") Or 
    userAgent.Contains("blackberry;") Or
    userAgent.Contains("samsung;") Or 
    userAgent.Contains("nokia;") Or 
    userAgent.Contains("sonyericsson;") Or
    userAgent.Contains("symbian;") Then
            Device = Modes.SmartPhone
 Else
            Device = Modes.OtherPhone
 End If
```