# How can we make audio works in all browsers, what primitive can we use if a browser doesn't support it?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, compatibility

Well I am writing a web application using JavaScript and HTML5 and  I have to put a sound notification in my web page, this is how I am calling it in JavaScript:

```
sounds: {
    bip: new Audio('/sounds/bip.mp3') 
}
```

But I want to make sure that this audio works in all browsers. So I have two questions:

1. How can I check if the audio works in all browsers?

I saw all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1514577/3669624) and I also found solutions here:

- [**DETECTING HTML5
  FEATURES**](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html).
- [**Using document.createElement() to test for browser support for an
  element**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck.shtml)

So there was an answer for this question:

```
var test_audio= document.createElement("audio"); //try and create sample audio element
var audiosupport=(test_audio.play)? true : false;
```

But my problem now is:

2. How can I make sure that the audio will always play in all browsers? How can I replace the `Audio()` element with an alternative and compatible one?

How can I manage this?

Comment: You can check here (http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio) to see what are all the browsers that support `Audio`, there are only two that don't which are IE8 and Opera Mini, which both make like 5% as global usage.

Comment: Implementing a backup for `<audio>` would be a waste of time, those browsers are few and dying, let them die. However, you might want to include alternative `<source>` elements since codec support can still vary. Ensure all supporting browsers can decode at least one of your audio files.

Comment: You can use the <object> element for browsers that do not support.

Comment: @Khalid Thanks a lot, but I just wanted to find a way to make it work with all browsers to avoid some compatibility problems.

Comment: @RoumelisGeorge how can we do it using the `<object>` element?

Comment: @Touffy as you said the `<source>` element is used to specify more codecs and does'nt make a browser support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this as an alternative for browsers that do not support audio element

```
<object data="/sounds/bip.mp3" >
<param name="src" value="/sounds/bip.mp3"/>
</object>
```

With JavaScript you could use something like this:

```
var obj = document.createElement('object'), 
    param = document.createElement('param');

param.name = "src";
param.value = "/sounds/bip.mp3";

obj.appendChild(param);
document.body.appendChild(obj);
```

You can check wether to use this or notusing Modernizr or with your code (have not tested):

```
var test_audio= document.createElement("audio"); //try and create sample audio element
var audiosupport=(test_audio.play)? true : false;
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to work with HTML and JavaScript both, take a look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/v34ux78f/).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned above you can easily check the compatibility, but I think as you can see in the comments this feature is rarely unsupported and there are **few old browsers** that doesn't support it and the main problem here is the MP3 codec support which you can test it with `canPlay()` and you can assure it like this:

```
var audio=document.createElement("audio");
audio.controls="controls";
//The mp3 source
   var mp3Source=document.createElement("source");
   mp3Source.src="myFile.mp3";
   mp3Source.type="audio/mpeg";
//the ogg source
   var oggSource=document.createElement("source");
   oggSource.src="myFile.ogg";
   oggSource.type="audio/ogg";
//Append the source elements to the audio
audio.appendChild(mp3Source);
audio.appendChild(oggSource);
```

Your currently used `new Audio()` construtor provides access to the properties of `<audio>` elements, as well as methods to manipulate them using :

```
mySound = new Audio([URLString]);
```

Take a look at [**MDN HTMLAudioElement Specifications**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) where you can see that the `new Audio()` construtor is basically supported by approximately all browsers as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: avoid MP3 if you can. Opus and AAC together should cover all current browsers.